# VSCode extension's API: JS contribution point

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VS Code extension that offers auto completion and hover information about my custom web components library.

I am using [Custom Data Extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-data-extension) to do that, but I have found that the only allowed contribution point are HTML and CSS, and that's a problem for me as I want to make my extension work in JSX files that uses my components in their React version (for instance: `<MyComponent>` instead of `<my-component>`)

I have not been able to find if this is possible, or so far, it seems not to be.

Any idea if this is supported by the current VSCode API?

Answer (score 0):

Originally answered by Simon Chan on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/153691#issuecomment-1170130215)

Usually providing completions for JSX is by writing a TypeScript definition file. The documentation is at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#intrinsic-elements

This file is usually distributed in an NPM package. I can't remember the rule for loading ambient definitions @mjbvz. Maybe it must be a @types/X package, otherwise the user has to edit their tsconfig.json or adding a /// <reference in their source files.

If you want to go the hard way by creating a plugin for TypeScript server that provides custom completions, I can only say it's not impossible. The related contribution point is typescriptServerPlugins: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.typescriptServerPlugins.